# query with OneToMany - openJPA vs EclipseLink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, openjpa

openjpa is complaining about an incorrect argument for a JPA query that EclipseLink properly handles.  EclipseLink returns the set of validation messages for the motor.

Two questions:
1) Is my query wrong and EclipseLink is kindly handling it anyway?
2) Any suggestions on how to restructure the query for openjpa?

Thanks for thinking about my question!

Query

```
SELECT m.valMessages FROM ThreePhaseMotorInput m WHERE m.id = :id
```

Actual openjpa exception

```
Caused by: <openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: 
Query projections cannot include array, collection, or map fields.  
Invalid query: "SELECT m.valMessages FROM ThreePhaseMotorInput m WHERE m.id = :id"
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ExpressionStoreQuery$AbstractExpressionExecutor.assertNotContainer(ExpressionStoreQuery.java:328)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ExpressionStoreQuery$DataStoreExecutor.<init>(ExpressionStoreQuery.java:770)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ExpressionStoreQuery.newDataStoreExecutor(ExpressionStoreQuery.java:179)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.createExecutor(QueryImpl.java:749)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForDataStore(QueryImpl.java:707)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForExecutor(QueryImpl.java:689)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compile(QueryImpl.java:589)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1038)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1017)
```

ThreePhaseMotorInput mapping

```
public class ThreePhaseMotorInput implements IThreePhaseMotorInput, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8084370807289186987L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Version
    private Integer version;
    private Integer status;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true, targetEntity = UnapprovedThreePhaseMotor.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "unapproved_id")
    private IThreePhaseMotor unapprovedMotor;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true, targetEntity = ApprovedThreePhaseMotor.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "approved_id")
    private IThreePhaseMotor approvedMotor;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = ValidationMessage.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "input_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    @OrderColumn(name = "idx")
    private List<IValidationMessage> valMessages;
```

ValidationMessage mapping

```
public class ValidationMessage implements Serializable, IValidationMessage {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8765213112015434057L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "record_id")
    private Long recordId;
    @Column(name = "field_name")
    private String fieldName;
    @Column(name = "validation_msg")
    private String validationMsg;
    private Integer status;
    @Column(name = "fail_field")
    private String failField;
    @Column(name = "error_source")
    private Integer errorSource;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html#bnbvx - SELECT clause: A SELECT clause cannot specify a collection-valued expression. For example, the SELECT clause p.teams is invalid because teams is a collection.
But you can use valMessages for INNER/OUTER join and select IValidationMessage entities trough it, e.g.:

```
SELECT ivm
  FROM ThreePhaseMotorInput tpmi
 INNER JOIN tpmi.valMessages ivm
 WHERE tpmi.id = :id
```

Comment: Thanks!  I thought I tried it before posting but must not have because your code worked the first time.